# How do I launch a webpage from a XUL app within XULRunner?

Tags: javascript, xul, xpcom, xulrunner

What is the XULRunner equivalent of the following button handler?

```
function launch_page() {
    var win = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1']
        .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator)
        .getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser');
    win.openUILinkIn('http://www.google.com', 'window');
}
```

This does not do anything in my XUL app that's installed to Program Files using XULRunner --install-app ./foo.xpi.

Is there any way for my XUL app to launch the user's default browser to display a web page on a button click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Opening_a_Link_in_the_Default_Browser) works for now:

```
// first construct an nsIURI object using the ioservice
var ioservice = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"]
    .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIIOService);

var uriToOpen = ioservice.newURI("http://www.google.com/", null, null);

var extps = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/uriloader/external-protocol-service;1"]
    .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIExternalProtocolService);

// now, open it!
extps.loadURI(uriToOpen, null);
```

Anybody got a more standard way?

Comment: I'd say this is correct code for a non-browser XUL application. Things get more complicated when you're writing an extension that you want to be able to install in both browser and non-browser XUL applications.